# How to delete the last latter using str replace

Tags: php

how to delate the last latter of this words

Drama, Horror, Life, Manga, Novel, Romance, School, Thriller,

i want to delete the last comma from Thriller,

i try this one

```
$var = 'Drama, Horror, Life, Manga, Novel, Romance, School, Thriller,';
    echo substr_replace($var, 'bob', 0, -1) . "<br />\n"; ?>
```

output

```
bob,
```

all deleted except the lastest comma from Thriller

Comment: Just [rtrim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) the trailing comma

Comment: wow, im wasted 1 hour just for trying solve that. LOL.. thanks bro

Comment: Read the docs for substr_replace. `substr_replace($var, '', -1, 1)` is how it would work. `rtrim` is a better solution though because the intent of the code is clear. It will help when you go back in 6 months and can't remember what  substr_replace was being used for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var = 'Drama, Horror, Life, Manga, Novel, Romance, School, Thriller,';
echo substr_replace($var, 'bob', strlen($var)-1, 1) . "<br />\n";
```

The `strlen` function return the length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use rtrim to do this:

```
$newstring = rtrim($var, ", ");
```